# Angular: one or two compilers?

Tags: angular

I've seen quite a few articles talking about two compilers in Angular by differentiating JIT and AOT. In my opinion, there is **only one Angular compiler** and JIT/AOT are just different approaches.

Are there really two Angular compilers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search the code base of angular, you shall clearly find 2 sub-directories in the *compiler* section

- [aot](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/compiler/src/aot)
- [jit](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/compiler/src/jit)

So, the hard answer to your question is: **yes**, there **are** two `Angular` compiler.

However, I presume they share a lot in common. Hence your statement.

Bottom line is the `jit` compiler transpiles an `Angular` project to plain JavaScript and HTML while it is being served, whereas the `aot` compiler transpiles it before it is being served.
Therefore, the `aot` compiler can bring in many more features than the `jit` compiler: performance, security, size...
The `aot` compiler seems to be much more complex than the `jit` compiler is.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my point. However, then another question  arises: When running `ngc` which of the two compilers is being used?

Comment: Actually, I'm not familiar with `ngc`, but it seems related to `aot`. Maybe you should check out this [article](https://www.usefuldev.com/blog/post/using-ngc-to-build-an-angular-2-library-project) and the `Angular` documentation. Happy I could help.